# Sync new clients added in civiCRM to mailchimp

Tags: email, mailchimp

I have started to use civiCRM on wordpress recently.
I have been using mailchimp for sending newsletter.
If I add new client in civiCRM, I want them to be added to mailchimp client newsletter list automatically. One way traffic only at the moment - from civiCRM to mailchimp when I add a client.
And second, if someone unsubscribes from newsletter list, how can I automatically (?) update in civiCRM this newsletter list?
how can I do this automatically?

Many Thanks

Comment: Not adding this as an answer, but you might want to explore the Mosaico extension in case that lets you switch away from MailChimp and therefore have full internal 'integration' of mail, bounce, clickthrough, opt-out etc with CiviCRM

Answer (score 2):

There is an extension that keeps MailChimp and CiviCRM synchronized. You can find it [here](https://civicrm.org/extensions/mailchimp-civicrm-integration)

This extension allows you to configure groups or smart groups in CiviCRM so that they synchronise (in either direction) with Mailchimp lists.

The extension is compatible with CiviCRM 4.7.x and 5.x.x versions (Extension compatibility with 4.7.x generally implies forward-compatibility with 5.x.x)